# Gradient disappearing after first epoch in manual linear regression

Tags: pytorch

I'm new to Pytorch and I've been working through the tutorials and playing around with toy examples. I wanted to just make a super simple model to get a better handle on autograd, but I'm running into issues.

I'm trying to train a linear regression model but I keep running into the following error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-ba5ca34a3a54> in <module>()
      9   loss = torch.dot(delta, delta)
     10 
---> 11   loss.backward()
     12   with torch.no_grad():
     13     w, b = w - learning_rate*w.grad.data, b - learning_rate*b.grad.data

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     91                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
     92         """
---> 93         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     94 
     95     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     87     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     88         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 89         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     90 
     91 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

And for reference, the code is here,

```
# dataset for training
X = torch.randn(100, 3)
y = -3*X[:,0] + 2.2*X[:,1] + 0.002*X[:,2] + 1

w = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)  # model weights
b = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)  # model bias


num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 1e-4

for i in range(num_epochs):

  y_hat = torch.mv(X, w) + b
  delta = y_hat - y
  loss = torch.dot(delta, delta)

  loss.backward()
  with torch.no_grad():
    w, b = w - learning_rate*w.grad, b - learning_rate*b.grad
```

The issue seems to be that after the first epoch the gradient attribute is set to None, but I'm a little confused why this would be the case.

If I try to zero the gradient after updating the weights, then I get a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in [locally disabling gradient computation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#locally-disabling-gradient-computation). As you can see in the first example, computations carried out with the `torch.no_grad()` context manager result in tensors for which `requires_grad == False`. Since you create "fresh" `w` and `b` instead of updating them in place, these tensors lose the `requires_grad` property after the first iteration and you get the error on 2nd iteration. A simple fix is to reenable gradients

```
with torch.no_grad(): 
    w, b = w - learning_rate*w.grad, b - learning_rate*b.grad 
    w.requires_grad_(True) 
    b.requires_grad_(True)
```

If you look up the source of optimizers in pytorch `optim` module, such as [`SGD`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD), you will see that they use the in-place operators such as `add_`. You can rewrite your loop in this manner

```
with torch.no_grad(): 
    w.sub_(learning_rate*w.grad)
    b.sub_(learning_rate*b.grad)
```

which will not touch the `requires_grad` flag, since the tensors keep their "identity" - just change values. In this case, you will need to remember to call `w.zero_grad()` and `b.zero_grad()` in each iteration or the gradient values will keep additively growing.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.